# ADB cannot open account settings that list and allows to add accounts

Tags: android, adb

I'm trying to use `ADB` to open one of the device settings. The setting screen that I want is the one that lists and allows us to add accounts to the device.

For example, `adb shell am start -a android.settings.ADD_ACCOUNT_SETTINGS` shows the accounts I can add.

I've managed to find that android shows the fragment `com.android.settings.accounts.AccountDashboardFragment` so tried to:

`adb shell am start -n com.android.settings/com.android.settings.SubSettings -e :android:show_fragment com.android.settings.accounts.AccountDashboardFragment`

but that throws:

```
adb shell am start -n com.android.settings/com.android.settings.SubSettings -e :android:show_fragment com.android.settings.accounts.AccountDashboardFragment
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.android.settings/.SubSettings (has extras) }

Exception occurred while executing 'start':
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.settings/.SubSettings (has extras) } from null (pid=24379, uid=2000) not exported from uid 1000
    at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStackSupervisor.checkStartAnyActivityPermission(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1043)
    at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.executeRequest(ActivityStarter.java:999)
    at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.execute(ActivityStarter.java:669)
    at com.android.server.wm.ActivityTaskManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityTaskManagerService.java:1096)
    at com.android.server.wm.ActivityTaskManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityTaskManagerService.java:1068)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAsUserWithFeature(ActivityManagerService.java:3662)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerShellCommand.runStartActivity(ActivityManagerShellCommand.java:544)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerShellCommand.onCommand(ActivityManagerShellCommand.java:186)
    at android.os.BasicShellCommandHandler.exec(BasicShellCommandHandler.java:98)
    at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:44)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onShellCommand(ActivityManagerService.java:10505)
    at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:929)
    at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:813)
    at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:5053)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2867)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1159)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1123)
```

Any idea how to bypass this?