# ADB how to find setting and extract coordinates so I can perform a click programatically?

Tags: android, adb

This is following this question: [ADB cannot open account settings that list and allows to add accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67256716/adb-cannot-open-account-settings-that-list-and-allows-to-add-accounts)

I know that
1 - `adb shell am start -a android.settings.SETTINGS` opens the device settings
2 - with `adb exec-out uiautomator dump /dev/tty` I can get the UI dump

I can see that

```
<node index="0" text="Passwords &amp; accounts" resource-id="android:id/title" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.android.settings" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[198,1361][752,1441]" />
```

is the option that I'm after, and I could extract from there the coordinates, so I can tap on the setting programmatically.

The problem is that there is not a unique identifier (this differs from device to device and OS version).
How can someone uniquely identify a setting?

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cn.trinea.android.developertools does this to change de Don't Keep Activity Setting.

Answer (score 1):

Using [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) you can do something like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient

device, serialno = ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit()
device.startActivity(component='com.android.settings/.homepage.SettingsHomepageActivity')
vc = ViewClient(device, serialno)

MAX = 3
count = 0
text = "Accounts"

while True:
    vc.findViewByIdOrRaise("com.android.settings:id/main_content_scrollable_container").uiScrollable.flingForward()
    vc.dump(window=-1)
    try:
        vc.findViewWithTextOrRaise(text).touch()
        break
    except:
        count += 1
        if count > MAX:
            raise RuntimeError(f"Coulnd't find {text}");
```

remember that you may need to scroll the list if the item you are looking for is not in view (`dump` does not include off screen items).

Also if the text is different you can adapt it to your android version and you can also use a regexp.